# Check value in python dict

Tags: python

I'm trying to get keywords from user input, if there are words in the lexicon(dict)，then return a tuple (token, word), else return ('error', word)

I stored the lexicon data in a dictionary, which each key holds multiple values, and loop it see if the input word is in one of them.

```py
lexicons = {
    'direction': ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
    'noun': ['car', 'bike'],
}

def scan(sentence):

    result = []
    words = sentence.split()

    for key, value in lexicons.items():  
        for word in words:
            found = 0
            if word in value:
                found += 1
            else:
                pass

            if found == 1:
                result.append((key, word))
            else:
                result.append(('error', word))

    return result

scan('car bike QWER')
```

I expect the of to be:

`[('noun', 'car'),('noun', 'bike'),('error', 'QWER')]`

but I got:

`[('error', 'car'),('error', 'bike'),('error', 'QWER'),('noun', 'car'),('noun', 'bike'),('error', 'QWER')]`

I know that is because it will check every key in the dict, but I have no clue how to modify it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should swap looping over the dictionary and looping over the sentence. Just imagine you holding a dictionary (a book!) and flipping through the pages, checking for every word in the dictionary, if there's such word among those you want to translate. Usually people do the opposite, take a word in a sentence and look for it in a dictionary. Try to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
lexicons = {
    'direction': ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
    'noun': ['car', 'bike'],
}

def scan(sentence):

    result = []
    words = sentence.split()

    for word in words:
        found = False
        for key, value in lexicons.items():              
            if word in value:
                found = True
                result.append((key, word))
                break
        if not found:
            result.append(('error', word))
    return result

scan('car bike QWER')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def scan(sentence):

    result = []
    words = sentence.split()

    # For each word, you want to see whether it is a dictionary key.
    # So swap the order of your loops:
    for word in words:
        for key, value in lexicon.items():
            if word in value:
                # With this method we don't need the 'found' flag. Just add it immediately.
                result.append((key, word))
                # Now, if we've found something, we can break our of the loop.
                break
        # Here I'm going to use a neat special feature of Python, the for loop 'else'. 
        # Isn't needed, but works nicely in these types of cases.
        # Basically, if nothing is found in the loop, then Python will run this.
        # Google it if you don't know about it.
        else:
            result.append(('error', word))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make your outside iterator (your first `for` loop) from the words you are testing, because that helps you output the same number of results as you are inputting (this isn't a 'golden rule', just a useful idea for the problem you are solving).

The rest of the logic should be easy to follow -- we start with a `found` variable set to `False`. If we find the word we are testing in one of our lexicons values, we change `found` to `True` and we break the loop as we have the values we need. We append the values to `result` and then continue testing the next input word.

If we finish testing the current word against the lexicon values and haven't found a match, we catch this in the `else` clause of the `if found:` statement and append an error to `result` and, again, continue.

```
lexicons = {
    'direction': ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
    'noun': ['car', 'bike'],
}

def scan(sentence):

    result = []
    words = sentence.split()

    for word in words:
        found = False
        for key, value in lexicons.items():
            if word in value:
                found = True
                break

        if found:
            result.append((key, word))
        else:
            result.append(('error', word))

    return result

scan('car bike QWER')
```

Comment: `break` will break the loop and result will be always empty.

Comment: Actually, the `break` only breaks the inner loop, which is the intended behaviour. Also: I tested the above before posting, and it returns the result expected by OP. Perhaps you could test at your end to confirm.

Comment: ok, stand corrected. please edit something in your answer, so t could remove the downvote?

Comment: I have edited the post, many thanks for reviewing your response, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def scan(sentence):
    # For a string in a list of strings
    for word in sentence.split():
        # Iterate as key-value pairs
        for key, value in lexicons.items():
            # If a word in the lexicons values
            if word in value:
                # yield (output) the a key-word pair tuple
                yield (key, word)

                # Exit from the for loop
                # . This will not run the code in else statement
                break
        else:
            # If no word was found in value
            # yield a tuple of key='error' and word
            yield ('error', word)
```

This function outputs a generator. It is using the `for-else` pattern in python. This is equivalent to having a `return` as the `if word in value`, or appending the `(key, word)` into a list.

I opt to use `yield` over `append`, given that you won't have to wait for the entire sequence to be evaluated before accessing each element. The generator will simply output the `(key, word)` as they are found (aka lazy evaluation). This is more memory efficient than loading the entire list into memory in one go. I also find that it leads to cleaner code.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, you should explain what code does too.

Comment: I have added an explanation. Thank you for your advice.